# Traffic or the traffic?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Should there be "the" in the blank space below or not? And why?

Not having a car in LA is not really an option since there is no public transportation system to speak of. As a result, _____ traffic is just awful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I would use a "the". Although the referent of the traffic isn't mentioned, it's still identifiable in the context (because it refers to the traffic in LA) . Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English calls this **an indirect anaphoric use of "the"** because the referent isn't overt, but it's indirectly associated with the main topic in the discourse.